Sum of a non telescopic series
I am trying to calculate the sum of the following series:
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1})$.
I know from Wolfram Alpha that the sum should be $1-\log(2)$, but the series is not telescopic and I am not able to reduce the general term to something familiar with the Taylor expansion of the logarithm.
Do you have any hint on how to do it?

What is the Taylor expansion of the logarithm?  For example $\log(1+x)=x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-\frac14x^4+\cdots$ where it converges, and letting $x=1$ and looking at partial sums resembles partial sums of $\sum (\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1})$

Write out a few terms:
$$\newcommand{\r}[2]{\color{red}{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\b}[2]{\color{blue}{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k+1}
=   \b 1 2 - \r 1 3 + \b 1 4 - \r 1 5 + \b 1 6 - \r 1 7 + \cdots
$$
With this in mind, we can clearly rewrite the series as
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}= 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}= 1 - \ln 2
$$

I was about to say, "But wait! This series only converges conditionally. Aren't you rearranging its terms and assuming the sum is the same?" But you're not rearranging terms, of course; you're writing the same terms in the same order with a different formula.

lol yeah I fretted over that myself for a hot minute after posting.
